# The expression « en prendre plein les yeux » and other variants

Tags: expressions

> Ces bijoux sont tous magnifiques. On **en prend plein les yeux**.

You can use this expression when you are dazzled by something/someone you see, « quand on trouve qqch/qqn si époustouflant que l'on ne peut pas en détourner le regard », correct?

Do the following variants work as well, depending on whether you see it, hear it, smell it, or taste it?

> On en prend plein **les yeux**.
>
> On en prend plein **les mirettes**.
>
> On en prend plein **la vue**.
>
> On en prend plein **les oreilles**.
>
> On en prend plein **les narines**.
>
> On en prend plein **les dents**.

or some others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On en prend plein les yeux.
>
> On en prend plein les mirettes.
>
> On en prend plein la vue.

... mean the same thing, with *yeux* and *vue* being maybe more idiomatic.

> On en prend plein les oreilles.

... is not an expression, and if used it means *hearing something really loud, too loud*.

> On en prend plein les narines.

... is not an expression, and same as the one with *oreilles*, I would understand it as *it really smells*, either it's good or bad.

> On en prend plein les dents.

... is an expression but means *to get a slap in the face*, either it's figurative or for real.

Figurative example :

> J'ai eu une mauvaise note en maths, quand mes parents ont appris ça j'en ai pris plein les dents.

Real case example :

> Hier soir on est tombé sur une bande rivale et ça a fini en bagarre, on en a pris plein les dents.

Comment: In what context would you use "en prendre plein les dents"? An example sentence would help greatly. Merci.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Added.

Comment: Great examples that really help to let the expressoin sink in! Merci. :)